# Insert Link in a Button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a reusable 'button' component and I want to insert a route in one of them to go to another page, I tried putting the `<Link> </Link>` but it takes my CSS and the 'button' is small.
It works if I just put it on the text, but it would be really bad to have to click on just the text to take it to another page;

###### Component Button

```
import React from 'react';

type ButtonProps = {
  style: React.CSSProperties;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

function MouseOver(event: any) {
  event.target.style.opacity = '90%'
}
function MouseOut(event: any) {
  event.target.style.opacity = ''
}

function Button({ style, children }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button
      onMouseOver={MouseOver}
      onMouseOut={MouseOut}
      style={style}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button;
```

###### Reusing

```
<Button
              key={id}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: '1.6rem',
                borderRadius: '4px',
                border: 'none',
                display: 'block',
                padding: '1rem',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                fontFamily: '"Roboto", sans-serif',
                transition: 'all 0.3s'
              }}
            >
              Create your account
            </Button>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Nowhere in the example code is `Link` used. Also, you should put event handler functions *inside* the component.

Comment: I used it this way ```<Link><Button></Button></Link```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wrap your button with a `<Link>` and pass the href with a prop:

```
function Button({ style, children, href }) {
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <button
        onMouseOver={MouseOver}
        onMouseOut={MouseOut}
        style={style}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

I would abstract this in a `<ButtonLink>` component like:

```
function ButtonLink({ style, children, href}) {
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <Button>
        {children}
      </Button>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement an onClick on the button and do your routing there.

```
function Button({ style, children, href }) {
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    //  your redirection logic here (example with history api):
    history.push("/some/url")
  }
  return (
      <button
        onMouseOver={MouseOver}
        onMouseOut={MouseOut}
        onClick={clickHandler}
        style={style}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
  )
}
```

Your implementation here really depends on what API you use for routing/redirecting. In your case it sounds like your `<Link>` component is an actual html `<a>` tag, since it's changing the style of the children. Make sure you're using a link component from your router library (ex. react-router https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

PS: it's good practice to define methods in the function component's function body, instead of outside of them (see last example).

Answer (score 0):

Link's can be so brutal. Does it have an href="" attribute? Have you tried playing around with that? I think i've usually create buttons with href's and they don't limit the link to just the text.